# Чтение json и добавление в базу данных mssql

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, mvc

Такой вопрос. Есть база данных в json формате.В консольном приложении сериализовал его при помощи newtonjson, и вывел через foreach.

```
 var LostData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Lost>> 
 (File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\My project\DB 
 LostPeople\mvswantedbezvesti_1.json"));

 foreach (var data in LostData)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Пропавший № {data.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{data.LAST_NAME} - {data.FIRST_NAME} - {data.MIDDLE_NAME} ");
            Console.WriteLine($"Дата рождения:{data.BIRTH_DATE}, Пол:{data.SEX}, Район:{data.OVD}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Дата исчезновения:{data.LOST_DATE}, Место исчезновения:{data.OVD} ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");


        }
```

Вопрос в в следующем, как лучше всего записать эти данные в базу данных mssql. Основная часть делается на mvc. Спасибо заранее за ответы. P.S. Я новичок.

Comment: какая БД будет использоваться?

Comment: mssql - реляционная БД, то есть вам надо будет создать таблицы и писать данные в них

Comment: Да, MSSQL.  Думаю может стоить создать сущности и контекст в консольном приложении и на прямую добавлять в базу.  Будет такая себе загрузочная программа.

Comment: Если первая бд маленькая, то можно и так. Если большая, то bulk insert вам в помощь

Comment: Прямо говоря вопрос слишком общий, я бы порекомендовал почитать буквари по EF: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/